# Use a Sony MD version 2 simple burner on Windows 7 Premium

Tags: windows-xp

I have a Windows 7 Home Premium PC, and I want to run my Sony SonicStage version 2.0 AE recorder on my PC, Ive read stuff about a XP Virtual Machine, but it all seems a bit over my head. Can anyone help and advise. Also I have got a copy of XP Professional on a disk and I have made a virtual hard drive on my PC, but I've been unable to open the virtual hard drive, plus I don't know how to put XP on the VHD, so I'm snookered, very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

A Virtual hard drive is just a virtual hard drive... it isn't that useful on its own.

Unfortunately with Windows 7 premium, you do not qualify for XP mode - it is only available in Ultimate/Professional/Enterprise.

As you have a Windows XP disk though, I recommend you download either [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/), or [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org).

Install this, then (the process for either are very similar) - select new virtual machine. Next, you want ideally 1GB of memory and to set a hard drive of a minimum of 20GB (safest to do 50-100 if you select incremental/do not allocate... This will start the hard drive very small and only grow when you add to it).

Then, plop in your Windows XP disk and install it like you would a regular computer.

When you want to use your device, just plug it in to USB and make sure that it is passed through to the virtual machine - and use like normal.

This is annoying, but, if there are not up to date drivers for Vista/7, it really is the best way to go around it (providing you have made sure that selecting XP compatibility doesn't work).

Anyway, if it is anything like the old version of SonicStage I had to set up for my brother's Mini Disk Player, you are doing the right thing keeping it seporate from your main computer!